# Get an entry's abstract using bibtex and harvard.sty (or any other means)

Tags: bibtex, biblatex

I cut-and-paste my bib file entries using websites' "export citation" buttons (e.g., jstor or ssrn.com), often these come with an "abstract" entry. But I've never seen any bibtex or harvard.sty documentation that tells me how to input this into my tex file.

Is this possible? Or can I make my bibliography section include the abstract? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) package includes a `reading` style that will include abstracts into the (specially formatted) bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=reading]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  abstract = {This is the abstract.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Thanks! I should have known the solution involved biblatex.